# Spring request mapping custom annotations - ambiguous mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, annotations

I have the following Spring MVC Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "my-rest-endpoint")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<MyStuff> defaultGet() {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping(params = {"param1=value1", "param2=value2"})
    public MySpecificStuff getSpecific() {
        ...
    }

    @GetMapping(params = {"param1=value1", "param2=value3"})
    public MySpecificStuff getSpecific2() {
        return uiSchemas.getRelatedPartyUi();
    }
}
```

What I need is to make it more generic using custom annotations:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "my-rest-endpoint")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping
    public List<MyStuff> defaultGet() {
        ...
    }

    @MySpecificMapping(param2 = "value2")
    public MySpecificStuff getSpecific() {
        ...
    }

    @MySpecificMapping(param2 = "value3")
    public MySpecificStuff getSpecific2() {
        return uiSchemas.getRelatedPartyUi();
    }
}
```

I know that Spring [meta annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-meta-annotations) could help me with that.

So I define the annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, params = {"param1=value1"})
public @interface MySpecificMapping {

    String param2() default "";

}
```

That alone won't do the trick.

So I add an interceptor to deal with that "param2":

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {
            HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
            // get annotation of the method
            MySpecificMapping mySpecificMapping = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(MySpecificMapping.class);
            if (mySpecificMapping != null) {
                // get the param2 value from the annotation
                String param2 = mySpecificMapping.param2();
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(param2)) {
                    // match the query string with annotation
                    String actualParam2 = request.getParameter("param2");
                    return param2 .equals(actualParam2);
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

And include it into the Spring configuration of course.

That works fine but only if I have one such custom mapping per controller.

If I add two methods annotated with `@MySpecificMapping` even having different values of "param2" then I get an "ambiguous mapping" error of the application start:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'myController' method 
public com.nailgun.MySpecificStuff com.nailgun.MyController.getSpecific2()
to {[/my-rest-endpoint],methods=[GET],params=[param1=value1]}: There is already 'myController' bean method
public com.nailgun.MySpecificStuff com.nailgun.MyController.getSpecific() mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:576)
 - Application startup failed
```

I understand why it happens.

**But can you help me to give Spring a hint that those are two different mappings?**

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.3 with Spring Web 4.3.5

Answer (score 4):

`@AliasFor` is annotation for do things like this. 
Here is an example of custom annotation with `@RequestMapping`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @interface JsonGetMapping {
    @AliasFor(annotation = RequestMapping.class, attribute = "value")
    String value() default "";
}
```

and also example of use

```
@JsonGetMapping("/category/{categoryName}/books")
public List<Book> getBooksByCategory(@PathVariable("categoryName") String categoryName){
    return bookRepository.getBooksByCategory(categoryName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not bind annotations in the stack with their params and Spring will consider these two methods as methods with equal `@RequestMapping`.

But you *could* try make a trick: embed somehow your custom annotation enhancer before mapping builder and perform there annotations replacing:

1. Get all methods with annotation `@MySpecificMapping`:

   MySpecificMapping myMapping = ...;
2. Read `@RequestMapping` annotation for each such method, let say it will be

   RequestMapping oldMapping = ...;
3. Create new instance of the `@RequestMapping` class:

   `RequestMapping newMapping = new RequestMapping() {
          // ... rest methods
          @Override
          public String[] params() {
              // here merge params from old and MySpecificMapping:
              String[] params = new String[oldMapping.params().length + 1];
              // todo: copy old one 
              // ...
              params[params.length-1] = myMapping.param2();
              return params;
          }
     }`
4. Forcly assign this new `newMapping` to each method correspondingly instead of `oldMapping`.

This is quite tricky and complex, but this is only one way to achieve what you want, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way around this is to move your @RequestMapping annotation to the method level instead of the class level.

The error Spring is giving you is because Spring is binding multiple handlers on one path which is invalid. Maybe give us an example of the URL's you'd like to expose so we have a better overview of what you're trying to build.